# Как убрать предыдущий фрагмент из BackStack при возврате

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть навигация из 4 фрагментов (A, B, C1, C2), у навигации может быть два варианта:

1. A -> B -> C(1)
2. A -> B -> C(2)

То есть из фрагмента "B", можно перейти на фрагмент "C(1)" или "C(2)" (зависит от внутренней логики)

Требуется, при нажатии кнопки "Назад", реализовать логику:

1 вариант навигации: C(1) -> B -> A (тут все ок, стандартная логика навигации)

2 вариант навигации: C(2) -> A (а вот тут нужно как-то миновать фрагмент B)

**Подскажите, как можно реализовать такую логику?**

**Что уже попробовал**

Вариант 1: popBackStack() перед открытие фрагмента C2 из фрагмента B. Не подходит, когда отрабатывает код, на секунду видно фрагмент A

Вариант 2: При создании транзакции фрагмента B из фрагмента А, не добавлять его в бэк стэк. Не подходит, для 1 варианта навигации фрагмент должен быть в стэке.

Comment: если исполльзуете NavigationGraph, то можно снавигировать во Фрагмент А с  указанием `setLaunchSingleTop(true)`. тогда вы откроете Фрагмент А, но т.к. он уже существует и лежит в бэкстеке, он НЕ пересоздаться, а все, что лежит выше него - закроется.

Comment: popBackStackImmediate попробуйте.

Comment: как навигация происходит? если на фрагмент менеджере, то почему бы не использовать replace в транзакции, при переходе `B -> C(2)`?